# Getting Error : android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

```
try {
    URL rssUrl = new URL("http://blog.nerdability.com/2013/03/tech-building-rss-reader-android-app.html");
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    RSSHandler rssHandler = new RSSHandler();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(rssHandler);
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
    xmlReader.parse(inputSource);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    rss.setText("NETWORK ERROR 01");
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    rss.setText("NETWORK ERROR 02");
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    rss.setText("NETWORK ERROR 03");
}
//   rss.setText(rssResult);
return null;
```

I added this part of code doInBackground and i am getting the  android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: and then the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the variable `rss` that you use in the catchs is a view in your layout.

If I am correct, you can not set the text in your doInBackground method but rather return that text in that method and do it in the next setp, the onPostExecute, this method receives the result from doInBackground, so you can use the string there and set the text in your view.

Check more info in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: i have already set the text in onPostExecute...despite of it i am getting same exception

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace?